# Group and retain only a few fields in a MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm kinda new to Mongo and I'm facing some difficulties trying to retrieve and filter my data

My collection entries look like :

```
{_id:object, "field1":"value1", "field2":"value2", [...], "field n":"value n"}
```

I'm currently doing this query to only retrieve the necessary fields :

```
db;collection.aggregate({$project:{_id:"field1",field2:1}})
```

Which works and return

```
{_id:"value1", "field2":"value2"}
```

However, I'm getting way too much duplicated entries, so I'd like _id to be unique.
I saw there is a distinct() function but it can't be used with aggregate, so is there a way to do it using groups maybe ?

Have you any idea about how could I do ?

**EDIT:**

What I have :

```
[ { "_id" : ObjectId("5ebbf0e90cf269611e3d34a1"), "libelle" : "Libelle for 2903", "code" : "_2903" },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebd39b90cf20c0ce837a51b"), "libelle" : "Libelle for 2903", "code" : "_2903" },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebbcc0d0cf20c0ce8379819"), "libelle" : "Libelle for 15027", "code" : "_15027" },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eba930c0cf20c0ce83779bf"), "libelle" : "Libelle for 15027", "code" : "_15027" } ]
```

What I want my query to return :

```
[ { "_id" : "_2903", "libelle" : "Libelle for 2903" },
{ "_id" : "_15027", "libelle" : "Libelle for 15027" } ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use project

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 1,
      field2: 1
    }
  }
])
```

This helps to remove or add fields.. [Projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/)

---

**Update 1**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$rncp",
      "libelle": {
        "$first": "$libelle"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RZySafJWjNy)**

Comment: But I also want to replace the _id value with the value of an other field, so I also need to use group, do I ?

I just tried using aggregate([{$group:..},{$project:...}]) but it did not work :/

Comment: No need. you can use `$project` to project as another field https://mongoplayground.net/p/e2s8u2_OHgX

Comment: It works, thank you ! However I'm getting a massive amount of duplicated entries. I'm expecting ~1000 results and I'm getting over 140k. Is there a way to only keep one entry per _id ? I don't think I can use distinct() with aggregation, so I finally won't avoid group, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes its possible... But can you edit the question and put the actual problem that you are facing!

Comment: Show us some examples and expected output. Bcs when you do grouping, u need to decided which document u need to omit and which one you need to keep

Comment: I'm getting many completely identical entries (on every field). So there is not really any criterion on which to decide, taking arbitrarily the first one would be ok. Entries look like the one I put in the question.

Comment: But before querying, I need the current sample documents(with few fields only) and expected result. Otherwise we need to waste out time

Comment: I've just edited my question to  add this

Comment: It finally works perfectly, thank you very much !